# Why is detecting idEscala null when it try to save?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, mapping

I'm getting this error **Column 'idEscala' cannot be null** when I try to save the valoracio. But I already have the object Escala with its id.

What could it be this error?

**Method to save valoracio**

```
public Valoracio createValoracio(Escala escala, long idResident, long idUser) {
    logger.info("----------------initValoracio escala: " + escala);
    Valoracio valoracio = new Valoracio(escala, idResident, idUser);
    logger.info("----------------initValoracio valoracio: " + valoracio);

    preguntes = escalaPreguntaMgr.findByEscalaId(escala.getId());
    logger.info("----------------initValoracio num(" + preguntes.size() + ") pregunta: " + preguntes.get(0));

    ValoracioItem vitem = new ValoracioItem(valoracio, preguntes.get(0));
    vitem.setPregunta(preguntes.get(0));
    valoracio.addValoracioItem(vitem);
    logger.info("----------------initValoracio before save valoracio(idEscala): " + valoracio.getEscala().getId());
    logger.info("----------------initValoracio before save vitem: " + vitem);
    valoracioMgr.save(valoracio);

    return valoracio;
}
```

**Valoracio entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_valoracio")
public class Valoracio extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idEscala", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Escala escala;
```

**Escala entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_escala")
public class Escala extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "escala")
    private Collection<Valoracio> valoracions = new HashSet();
```

**EscalaManager method**

```
public Escala save(Escala escala) {
    return this.em.merge(escala);
}
```

**Error**

```
11:11:47,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-71) Hibernate: 
11:11:47,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-71)     /* insert es.imas.gestresi.business.pia.entity.Valoracio
11:11:47,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-71)         */ insert 
11:11:47,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-71)         into
11:11:47,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-71)             t_valoracio
11:11:47,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-71)             (dataAlta, idEscala, idResidentKronos, idUser, observacio, version) 
11:11:47,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-71)         values
11:11:47,557 INFO  [stdout] (default task-71)             (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
11:11:47,558 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-71) SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
11:11:47,558 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-71) Column 'idEscala' cannot be null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the method save() is calling the entity manager method merge to **save** the object, and in this case because the escala is not saved, it already does not have id.
In this case, when the object is still without id it is necessary to use method **persist** instead.

Change method **save** for **persist** when the object does not have an id.